# Outer Join not working as expected in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

- I have a customer master table `CUSTOMER_MASTER` it has a primary key `CUSTOMER_ID`.
- There are two more sub tables for the customers `CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1` AND `CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2` each table has its own primary key and the foreign key `CUSTOMER_ID`.
- Not all records in the master table `CUSTOMER_MASTER` have corresponding records in the said two sub tables.

I need to build a select statement that joins the three tables `CUSTOMER_MASTER`, `CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1` and `CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2` based on the key `CUSTOMER_ID`. But the problem is the records in `CUSTOMER_MASTER` that do not have corresponding records in the sub tables are not coming in the output even with outer join usage. See below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER MAS, CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1 SUB1, CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2 SUB2
WHERE SUB1.CUSTOMER_ID = MAS.CUSTOMER_ID(+)
AND   SUB2.CUSTOMER_ID = MAS.CUSTOMER_ID(+)
-- Other conditions for CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1 and CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2 are there.
```

My target is to select all the customers like below:

[image: Expected SQL Result]

DB is Oracle 11g

Comment: If you use Oracle proprietary, old, deprecated, not recommended notation for joins, you should use it correctly. To get an outer join like you are doing, the (+) should be on the side with "missing" rows (to remember it, think of the (+) as indicating an addition of fake rows TO THAT TABLE, on the side with the +).

Comment: I have added the (+) on the other side also and I got the same result.@mathguy

Comment: Start by never using implicit joins.

Comment: OK, I think I see what is happening. If you must use the old Oracle syntax... You may have conditions like `... and sub1.start_date > sysdate - 100`.  In such conditions, you must append the (+) to the left side also! Even if it is not a join condition. EVERY mention of the detail tables must have the (+) appended at the end.

Comment: @mathguy well... every mention that you want treated as a join/on condition vs a where condition. But best just to use modern syntax.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - 100% agreed.

Comment: How about reading the Oracle documentation for left join, which tells you everything here including not to use old style left join? PS Outer join is binary and the order you do them matters. After you have used a + condition to say one of the commas is an outer join, what do you expect a + condition involving one of those tables again to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use that obsolete old join syntax. It's less powerful (there are some things you can't express this way), it can be ambiguous (it's not always clear when a condition is part of a JOIN and when it's part of a WHERE clause, or which JOIN a condition belongs to), and it's harder to read because it mixes all the conditions from a query together. It's been more or less obsolete since at least 1999.

In this case, it's likely the "other conditions for 1&2" part are the problem. Since you have no distinction between JOIN and WHERE clause, they are applied as a WHERE clause. But in the case where there is no record from `CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1` or `CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2`, the condition is comparing with `NULL`, which effectively results in `FALSE`, and the whole `CUSTOMER_MASTER` record is excluded from the result set.

There's not always a good fix for this using the old syntax, but with modern join syntax it's easy. This will probably work as you expect:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER MAS
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1 SUB1 ON SUB.CUSTOMER_ID = MAS.CUSTOMER_ID
     -- AND other conditions for CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2 SUB2 ON SUB2.CUSTOMER_ID = MAS.CUSTOMER_ID 
     -- AND other conditions for CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2
```

This forces the additional conditions to be treated as part of the JOIN rather than the WHERE, such that they will not cause a `CUSTOMER_MASTER` record to be excluded.

Comment: In general you are right, however there is at least one case where you still have to use old Oracle join syntax: For MATERIALIZED VIEWs with FAST REFRESH. You cannot use FAST REFRESH if you use ANSI join in query.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That's something Oracle really needs to fix. But in the meantime, I've updated the answer to explain why it's important for this query.

Comment: Well, there's that problem, too. But when he fixes that he's still gonna have to deal with those extra conditions. This addresses both.

Comment: Long time ago I raised a ticket at Oracle due to this: Oracle does not consider this as a bug but just as a lack of documentation! I don't know how the situation is in current Oracle release. At least in 12.1 it was not solved.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - OK, I didn't read the question in all details until now. I do see the issue... I explained further in an additional Comment.

Comment: When (+) is present on only some references to a table then a cross join is done and there are not nulls, and otherwise the condition is part of determining the nulls. So it's not relevant to wonder about nulls failing tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query.  You can see schema and results on sqlfiddler 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40da3/3

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerId,
    c.MasterDetails,
    d1.Details1,
    d2.Details2
FROM
                  Customers c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerDetails1 d1
          ON d1.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerDetails2 d2
          ON d2.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
WHERE
    --Additonal where clause here
        1=1
    AND 2=2
    --etc
ORDER BY 
  c.CustomerId
```

Comment: I think Joel beat me to the punch...Only suggestion I have is that I really don't like including any where clause type stuff in the join section.  I prefer to have the join section be actual joins that link tables up and the where clause actually limit or filter the records.

Comment: WHERE clause is better, except when it has a different meaning. The purpose of moving those conditions to the JOIN/ON was to avoid excluding records he wanted to keep.

Comment: What Joel says there is absolutely correct. You can put single-table conditions in the WHERE clause or in the JOIN clause. In inner joins it makes no difference, but in outer joins it does; putting conditions in WHERE vs. JOIN serves different purposes and solves different problems.